# Save selected file in android sdcard

Tags: java, android

How can I save a file that was selected by user into an specific folder in android sdcard?

I followed [this article here that helped me a lot](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/android-how-to-select-file.html), but i don't know how to save it after that.

I am able to save selected images and pitcures that are taken. This is the code I use for it.

```
    private String saveBitmapToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    // get dir
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myApp/app-files");
    if (!dir.mkdirs()){
        Log.w("Could not create log directory: " + dir.getAbsolutePath(), "");
    }

    String fileName = "";
    if (ChecklistHandler.getWorkingItem().getChildren() == null || 
            ChecklistHandler.getWorkingItem().getChildren().isEmpty()){
        fileName = ChecklistHandler.getWorkingItem().getId() 
                + "_" + ChecklistHandler.getActivation() + ".jpg";
    } else {
        fileName = ChecklistHandler.getWorkingItem().getChildren().get(0).
                getId() + "_" + ChecklistHandler.getActivation() + ".jpg";
    }

    File mypath=new File(dir, fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dir.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

and then I save the reference in the given folder in my db.
I want to do the same with file. Save it in that same folder and then get the reference and save it.

Comment: Think a bit about what exactly you are trying to do.  If you have a literal filesystem file, perhaps what you want to do is to *copy* it to a path on the sdcard (or external storage in general).  There are a number of questions here on copying files with Android java code.  If you have some other data source, you'll want to write out its contents in a meaningful way to a destination file - much as you are doing for the bitmap, but perhaps without the convenience of an object method that takes a destination output stream.

Comment: The problem is that the use can select several files that are in the cloud to. If he does so, i wont have it inside the device, and wont be able to retrieve the file when sync with main server. That is why I am copying it to another folder, and, after synchronization, the files that were successfully sent are going to be erased by the system itself. But ill look with the way you suggested. Thanks